# Errors occuring when running simple Hello World in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Today is my first day learning C#. I am experienced with Java and C and usually don't run into problems I cant solve. I have always dreaded using Visual Studio due to the never ending errors I would receive when I use to run my assembly programs. Today I wanted to just run a simple `hello world` program. After running the program, I am getting the following errors.

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\cansh_000\source\repos\Program\Program\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Program.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Console.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.7\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[2852] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`
```

Code down Below

```
using System;
namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: None of that output is an error message. It says your program ran to completion successfully and then exited.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code.

Comment: Could we have a look at your program? My guess is that this is a console application and you didn't end your code with `Console.Read()` which is required so that you can see the output of your program without it exiting.

Comment: Is it a Console Application project that doesn't have any pause after executing?

Comment: I would suggest your code is running just fine.  You must remember that VS doesn't keep consoles open after they're finished it closes them immediately.

Comment: The other option is to actually open a console window and run your compiled program from there. You'll see your `Hello World` display in your console window

Comment: Finally, I found a solution ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of that output is an error message. It says your program ran to completion successfully and then exited. The C# compiler does not add a "Press any key to continue..." message after the program completes unlike some C compilers - so after the program runs it disappears leaving no-trace on screen.

Look for your `void Main`, `int Main`, (or `async Task Main`) method and add `Console.WriteLine("done!"); Console.ReadLine();` immediately before the closing curly brace `}`.

#### Update for Visual Studio 2019:

Since C# 8.0 in VS2019, the IDE now *does* run console-mode applications using a special host process that will add the "Press any key to continue..." message after the program has finished running.

Comment: Thanks. It helped out a lot. I am new so this is a learning experience. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

These aren't errors, they are just messages, showing that module XY was loaded. They can be very distracting from the debug messages you actually **want** to see.

If they disturb you (like me!) and you just want to turn off those messages in Visual Studio, there are two ways to do that:

---

**1st Way to disable it**

Go to
**Tools -> Options**, type "debugging" into the search box, navigate to the "Output Window" settings and turn **"Module Load Messages" Off.**

The screenshot below illustrates how find the setting:

[image: DebuggingOptions]

---

**2nd Way to disable it**

In the **Debug Output Window,** right-click to bring up the **context menu,** then **un-tick** the option as shown below:

[image: ContextMenu]

---

**Note:** I also turned the **Thread Exit Messages** off - together with the option above it reduces the noise in the output window significantly!

Answer (score 1):

As said before your program runs fine. The output window is just closed on exit.
The info messages you posted mean, that you are currently only debugging your own code (`Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`) and no framework code.
This is the 'Just my Code' setting. You can change this under Tools>Options>Debugging>General>Enable Just my Code.